# Zenity Not Showing Notification When Ran As Root

Tags: linux, bash, zenity

Forgive my stupidity but I'm trying to make a script that has to been ran as root to print a notification but it won't work for some reason??

It works just fine when ran without Sudo.
If I try to run it with sudo it gives me this error?? `** (zenity:14645): WARNING **: 16:25:09.209: Error showing notification: The connection is closed`

Could someone give me some insight to this issue and possible a solution?

Here is the command.
`echo 'message:Finished!' | timeout 0.1 zenity --notification --listen --display=:0.0`

Answer (score 0):

Testing here, mine only works if I pass `XDG_RUNTIME_DIR`, otherwise it hangs and eventually shows:

> Error showing notification: Error calling StartServiceByName for org.freedesktop.Notifications: Timeout was reached

And it needs to run as the target user, not root (not even if `xhost +` is allowed), or the same happens.

This works here:

```sh
sudo -u $USER --preserve-env=DISPLAY,XDG_RUNTIME_DIR \
  zenity --timeout 1 --notification --text test &
```

Gnome 3.30.2, zenity 3.30.0.